# Model displays properly but posts back null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, razor

I'm populated a partial view with a strongly-typed model. In this partial view is a form. When I submit the form it tells me that objects inside of my model are null, even though they are not because the partial view rendered all elements based on that same model.

More specifically, I'm having trouble passing back all of my checkboxes. If you look at my controller you can see that I check to see if `CompanyOptions` is null, and every time I run the program it prints `STUFF IS NULL`, meaning that it's null.

Model:

```
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    public CompanyOptions CompanyOptions;
}

 public class CompanyOptions
    {

        public CompanyLicenseOptions CompanyLicenseOptions { get; set; }
    }

 public class CompanyLicenseOptions
    {
        public List<CompanyLicenseOption> CompanyLicenseOptionsList;
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", FormMethod.Post))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[i].IsLicensed, checkboxHtmlAttributes);
        <label for="@Model.CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[i].LicenseName">@Model.CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[i].LicenseName</label>                                                                                       
        <br/>
    } 
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DatabaseName)
    <input id="submit_licenses" type="submit" style="display:none;" />
}
```

Controller:

```
       [HttpPost]
        public void Action(Company model)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("STUFF:" + model.DatabaseName);
            if(model.CompanyOptions!=null)foreach (var item in model.CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("STUFF:" + item);
            else System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("STUFF IS NULL");
        }
```

Generated HTML:

```
<input class="licenses" data-val="true" disabled="" id="CompanyOptions_CompanyLicenseOptions_CompanyLicenseOptionsList_0__IsLicensed" name="CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[0].IsLicensed" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[0].IsLicensed" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

The Irrelevant JS

```
$('#save_licenses').click(function () {
        swap_licenses(true);
        $('#submit_licenses').click();
    });
```

POST:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3080/Controller/Action
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[0].IsLicensed:false
    CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[1].IsLicensed:false
    CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[2].IsLicensed:false
    CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[3].IsLicensed:false
    CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[4].IsLicensed:false
    CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[5].IsLicensed:false
    CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[6].IsLicensed:false
    CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[7].IsLicensed:false
    CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[8].IsLicensed:false
    CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[9].IsLicensed:false
    CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[10].IsLicensed:false
    CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[11].IsLicensed:false
    CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[12].IsLicensed:false
    DatabaseName:myDb
```

Comment: I think `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[i].IsLicensed, checkboxHtmlAttributes);` will produce an incorrect naming convention that the model binder expects. What is the rendered HTML markup of the checkbox?

Comment: Your submit button seems to be hidden (`style="display:none;"`) so how are you submitting this form? Are you using some javascript? AJAX? Something else? Could you show your real code that is submitting this form?

Comment: @AdrianRefuerzo, no it will not produce incorrect naming convention.

Comment: Yes, I'm using JS for the button.

Comment: @Johannes, then what are you waiting for? We cannot read your mind. Where is this js? Any chance to see it?

Comment: @Johannes - how do you know it doesn't produce an incorrect naming convention? Have you looked at the POST in firebug or fiddler? Can you provide it here?

Comment: @JoshE, I know that it will not produce incorrect naming convention.

Comment: @Darin - EDIT: I'm partially illiterate it seems

Comment: @JoshE, I cannot post it because it's not me who wrote the code :-) It's the person who asked the question, duh. Unfortunately I cannot tell you what javascript code did `Johanes` wrote. That's why I asked him to show it.

Comment: JoshE, yeah, oops. @Johannes, so are you going to show your javascript or not? I already told you that your markup is correct.

Comment: I've posted the generated HTML. The JS is irrelevant, it's just an onclick event that clicks on the submit button and I know that it posts because I've looked at the POST.

Comment: No, the JS is not irrelevant, believe me :-) Let us judge what is relevant and what not. Also show the controller action that is supposed to handle this POST. What arguments does it take? Also it would help if you showed your `CompanyOptions` model. If you are not willing to collaborate I really do not see how we can help you.

Comment: What is `checkboxHtmlAttributes`?

Comment: What is `#save_licenses`? I cannot see an element with such id in your markup. Or at least in the portion of markup you have shown in your question.

Comment: Alright, I added the irrelevant JS :p -- The POST action controller side is already in my question. And I'm adding the CompanyOptions now..

Comment: @Darin - I suppose we both need more literacy lessons - the controller action was in the original post :)

Comment: @Johannes, `#save_licenses`?

Comment: checkboxHtmlAttributes just adds a CSS class to the HTML. I've added all other models now.

Comment: #save_licenses is the div they click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input class="licenses" data-val="true" disabled="" id="CompanyOptions_CompanyLicenseOptions_CompanyLicenseOptionsList_0__IsLicensed" name="CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[0].IsLicensed" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList[0].IsLicensed" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

Here's your problem:

```
disabled=""
```

Your checkbox is `disabled`, so nothing will ever get sent to the server. That's how HTML works. Disabled elements are never sent. So get rid of this attribute.

If you want to prevent the user from modifying the value, and yet the initial value get sent to the server use the `readonly` attribute, not `disabled`.

Also another problem I see with your code is with the `CompanyLicenseOptionsList` collection field. It should be a property with public getter and setter:

```
public class CompanyLicenseOptions
{
    public List<CompanyLicenseOption> CompanyLicenseOptionsList { get; set; }
}
```

Same stands true for your `CompanyOptions` field (you have defined it as a field, whereas it should be a property):

```
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    public CompanyOptions CompanyOptions { get; set; }
}
```

---

UPDATE:

Now that you have fixed the problem with your missing getters and setters, all that's left is make sure that all the models intervening in this object graph have default (parameterless) constructors. That's a requirement if you want they to appear as action argument because otherwise the default model binder wouldn't know how to instantiate them. If for some reason you cannot add a default constructor to all your objects, I would very strongly recommend you revise your object hierarchy and start using view models right away.

Comment: It isn't disabled when I submit the form, but for testing purposes I removed it altogether but the problem still persists.

Comment: Could you show what you see in FireBug? The exact payload of the POST request?

Comment: Alright, the POST payload seems fine and respects the naming conventions. I have updated my answer with another problem I've just noticed with your code.

Comment: Good catch with that getter/setter. Unfortunately the behavior hasn't changed.

Comment: What about the `IsLicensed` boolean field in your `CompanyLicenseOption` class? Did you make sure it has a public getter and setter? By the way I also notice that your controller action is `void`. Normally controller actions should return `ActionResult`. I don't think that this is related to your problem, I am just mentioning it for good practices sake.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I added the getter/setter to `CompanyOptions` I got this error message: `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`

Comment: Well, that's normal. Now the model binder kicks in. Except that some of your classes doesn't have a default constructor. The error message is pretty self explanatory. You must have a default (parameterless) constructors for all models in your object graph.

Comment: does changing the variable name of `public CompanyOptions companyOptions { get; set; }` help?

Comment: @AdrianRefuerzo, of course that it helps. The model binder in ASP.NET MVC is working with properties, not fields. It will not even attempt to bind them.

Comment: @Johannes, any progress on this? Did you add default constructors to all your objects?

Comment: All of my objects have default constructors but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Which error? `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`? If you are getting this error it means that you have an object somewhere in your graph which doesn't have a default constructor. It's as simple as that. You might try to analyze the inner exception and pinpoint the exact CLR type that is problematic.

Comment: I have no way of knowing what is breaking though, the stacktrace is all background .NET stuff, nothing relates to my code and breakpoints are useless.

Comment: What about the InnerException?

Comment: The only object I can see that could cause this issue is a `Guid`, as it doesn't have a default constructor, but when I removed the getters/setters from those, I still got the error. Also I'm not sure how to see the InnerException.

Comment: No, the Guid's fine. That's not the problem. Don't look at system classes. Look at your own classes. You are not sure how to see the InnerException? When the exception is thrown simply look at the `Innerexception` property. All exceptions have this property.

Comment: Is it a problem that I'm using the Entities as models?

Comment: Yes, that's a huge problem and a very bad design. You should never use your Entities like that. You should use view models - classes that are specifically designed to meet the requirements of your views. But if now it's too late to change your wrong design, you will have to start searching through the entities appearing in the `Company` object graph and identify the one that doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: By extension, I should also not include Entities inside of models, correct?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, you will have exactly the same problem if you do so. The model binder will attempt to instantiate some of your entities and it will fail because it probably doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: Alright. It's not my code, I was put on this project and changing the design means changing everything, which is no easy task given the size of this project. I'll take a look through the Company object.

Comment: I agree, changing the design of a badly architectured application is not an easy task. You will have to identify the object in your graph that is causing the problem. You could proceed by exclusion. Start by removing properties.

Comment: Thank you Darin, you were right, I was missing something, but it was buried very deep. Everything works great now. You've been a fantastic help. I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: I am very glad I could help you in finding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a foreach loop instead of a simple for, this way:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var option in Model.CompanyOptions.CompanyLicenseOptions.CompanyLicenseOptionsList)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(o => o.IsLicensed, checkboxHtmlAttributes);
        <label for="@option.LicenseName">@option.LicenseName</label>                                                                                       
        <br/>
    } 
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DatabaseName)
    <input id="submit_licenses" type="submit" style="display:none;" />
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the endpoint of all these checkboxes is a `List<T>`, you'll need to make sure that it is instantiated before use:

```
public class CompanyOptions
{
    public CompanyLicenseOptions CompanyLicenseOptions { get; set; }
}
public class CompanyLicenseOptions
{
    public List<CompanyLicenseOption> CompanyLicenseOptionsList;
    public CompanyLicenseOptions() 
    {
         CompanyLicenseOptionsList = new List<CompanyLicenseOption>();
    }
}
```

EDIT: To ensure that readers get proper context for this answer and avoid confusion, I've reproduced the OP code above mine.

Comment: -1, The default model binder cannot work with fields. Only with properties. So all you will get with this approach is an empty collection instead of NULL. You will never be able to bind the values coming from the view. See my answer for more details.

Comment: I just used what was provided in the OP, Darin. I appreciate the raw energy you apply to posting here at SO

Comment: But what the OP provided is wrong! So using it is wrong. That's the whole point. And that's why I downvoted your answer. Because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: yours doesn't either, and yet people refrained from downvoting until there's been sufficient opportunity to reflect and review upon it.

Comment: What makes you think that my post doesn't answer the question? I have explicitly pointed out the problems with the code that the OP showed. He used fields instead of properties and his objects do not have parameterless constructors. That's the origin of his problem and the reason why he gets NULL in the controller action. As far as your update is concerned, there's still a problem with it. See my first comment to your answer.